# Future-based API from Dart in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, dart

There are feature like [Future](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/futures/) from Dart in NodeJS ? If yes, how use it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart dicided to call the feature Future, but it's called Promise in the field of Javascript.
It is comming to Javascript as a [build in feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in the future. In the mean time you can use packages that bring the feature to Node.js, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351494/promises-pattern-in-node-js-libraries-to-use).

Comment: And there are a release date ? Because, we have been talking about ecmascript 6 since long ago..

Comment: The good thing about promises/futures is that it's not a language, but a library feature. We don't need native support to use this style of programing.